Laravel 6 app and Laravel 10 app sharing Cashier
I have a Laravel 6 app using Laravel Cashier (Stripe) with a large user base. I also have a Laravel 10 app using the same set of subscriptions. The problem is that the table fields have been changed in Casher between versions. Is there a way to resolve this?

Specifically, the Subscriptions model has a slightly different set of fields/names.

can't you update the l6 to l10? it's in EOL a long time and bad for security...

The Laravel 6 app is too big for an easy update - the resources required would not be economical. And the 6 app works fine so why fix it.

The ideal scenario would be to upgrade the Laravel 6 App, but since it's mentioned in the comments that it's not Economical, I'll skip that.
The next best approach to solve this IMO would be to keep the subscription-related code and tables in your Laravel 6 App and have it expose APIs that your Laravel 10 App uses to fetch/update subscriptions.
Pros

This follows modern microservice patterns and helps you avoid using the same database for both apps ( As someone who currently has 3 Laravel applications using the same database, I cannot stress how much of a pain it is to maintain ).

This also means that as long as you don't change the API exposed by the L6 App, you could upgrade it later to L11 and your L10 App won't be affected at all.


Cons

Following this approach means that you will not be able to use Laravel Cashier-related functions in your L10 app since all of them will be in the L6 App.

It also means you will only be able to use up to v12 of Laravel Cashier ( The last Cashier version that supports L6 ) in your L6 App ( unless you upgrade it of course ), so you will miss out on new features added recently by Cashier and Stripe APIs



This seems very limiting. I need to use all the features of Cashier in both apps. I am thinking that perhaps the newer version could be persuaded to use different field names, but not sure how that can be achieved.
